# JQGrid : deselect event

Tags: jquery, events, jqgrid

Using JQGrid, I know about the onSelectRow event when a row is selected.

I would like to know if there is an event when you deselect a row because you have selected another row.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still create your custom event:

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
        if (this.lastSel && id && id !== this.lastSel) {
            $(this).trigger('deselectRow', [this, this.lastSel]);
        }
        this.lastSel = id;
    }
```

And then bind event:

```
$("#grid").on('deselectRow', function(e, table, rowId){
    console.log(rowId); // $('#'+rowId, table);
});
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: it is worth mentioning that this method only works when selecting another row, not when clicking on the same row a second time to deselect.

Comment: Hi, I know it's an old answer - but what line of code specifically deselects the row? Your demo no longer works